# Why is `_.map` returning undefined when I return `false`?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have a function, which maps an array with `underscore`.  Here is the function:

```
var services = _.map(userCopy.get('services'), function (service) {
    if (service.service_selected === true) {
        return service;
    }
});
```

My problem is that when the `conditional === false`, then I get `undefined` put into `services`.  Of course I can remove the `undefined`, but that is ugly and I just want to use `map` correctly.  How do I fix this?

Comment: because if `conditional === false` javascript interpretator doesn't find any constructions and go to implicit return statement which returns `undefined` - http://shamansir.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/en/#core.undefined - to return `false` you must do it explicitly

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`_.map` uses whatever the function returns, to build the result. If a function doesn't return anything explicitly, JavaScript returns `undefined`. That's why the result of `_.map` has `undefined` whenever the condition fails.

What you actually need, is a [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter)

```
var services = _.filter(userCopy.get('services'), function(service) {
    return service.service_selected === true;
});
```

`_.filter` accepts a collection and a predicate function. It applies the predicate function to each and every value of the collection and if the function returns `true`, that element will be included in the result, if the function returns `false`, that element will be skipped.

**Note:** You can actually use [`_.matcher`](http://underscorejs.org/#matcher), along with `_.filter`, like this

```
var isServiceSelected = _.matcher({
    service_selected: true;
});

var services = _.filter(userCopy.get('services'), isServiceSelected);
```

This will be very useful if you are going to filter based on `service_selected: true` condition more than once. If it is just a one-time thing, then `_.where` shown below would be better alternative.

---

You can also use [`_.where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where), which can return the objects only if the current object contains all the key-value pairs listed, like this

```
var services = _.where(userCopy.get('services'), {
    service_selected: true;
});
```

Now, all the service objects will be returned which have `service_selected` attribute value as `true`.

---

**Demo:**

```js
function display(heading, data) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('h3')).innerHTML = heading;
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = json;
}


var data = [{
    "name": "auth",
    "service_selected": true
}, {
    "name": "authorization",
    "service_selected": false
}, {
    "name": "faltu",
    "service_selected": true
}];


display("_.filter", _.filter(data, function (service) {
    return service.service_selected === true;
}));

display("_.matcher", _.filter(data, _.matcher({
    service_selected: true
})));

display("_.where", _.where(data, {
    service_selected: true
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: However, filter returns the entire object when iterating over and object... rather than `_.map()` which allows returning just one property.

Comment: @doublejosh Correct, but OP wants the entire `service` object. I included an alternative with `_.where`, please check.

Comment: You can also roll something quick as this: `var missingParams = _.filter(missingParamsArray, Boolean);`

Answer (score 1):

Updated my answer... This solved my problem

```
    var missingParamsArray = _.map(requiredParams, function (val, param) {
        if (val) {
            if (!req.user[param]) {
                return param;
            }
        }
    });

    var missingParams = _.filter(missingParamsArray, Boolean);
```

missingParams can also be written as

```
var missingParams = _.filter(missingParamsArray, function (param) {
       return param !== undefined;
    });
```